# Add changes to systemd-udevd.service

Tags: yocto, udev

I want to add changes in systemd-udevd.service file in my source and after that build image with my changes. Is it possible?

After Build
Full path :

```
/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service.
```

Comment: Find recipe which delivers such file and create a patch file which needed modifications, [docs](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-tasks-patch) how to apply patch file.

Comment: Problem is that I don't know, where I can find it. In systemd dirs in my source and in udev dirs I don't see anything similar to this.

Comment: If such file was generated by a recipe, then should be stored in this location - _tmp/work/<arch target name>/<recipe name>/<pacakage version>/_ (in case that You don't use [rm_work](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#dev-saving-memory-during-a-build) ). But I found that [systemd_239.bb](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_239.bb?h=master), I am right ?

Comment: @lukaszgard you're right. I found system_234.bb in my source, but it isn't clear for my how to change a line line "MountFlags=slave" in systemd-udevd.service file.

Comment: If the file comes from sources then You need to create a patch file and add to SRC_URI (e.g. from systemd_239.bb - [link](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd/0001-Fix-to-run-efi_cc-and-efi_ld-correctly-when-cross-co.patch)), but if file was generated during compilation time, then You have to create a dedicated task [docs](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#tasks) with needed modifications. Good tip for You, there is a lot of examples in _meta/_ or _meta-openembedded/_ layers   achieving Your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd-udevd.service file is generated during compilation time. I added systemd_234.bbappend file with do_install_append(), which overwrite service config.

systemd_234.bbappend:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI += "file://systemd-udevd.service"

do_install_append() {
    cp ${WORKDIR}/systemd-udevd.service ${D}/lib/systemd/system
}
```

Me file tree in /poky/meta/recipes-core/systemd

```
.
├── files
│   └── systemd-udevd.service <- new config file
├── systemd
│   └── ...
├── systemd_234.bb
├── systemd_234.bbappend
└── ...
```